Anydesk is opening a port forward to my router , but port forward on router is Off
Since several days ago I've noticed a strange behaviour on my router.
On router logs , in Port forwarding section I've noticed a Port forward to one of my PC. ( this has happening to different PC in different time ).
On my router Options , Por  t forward is DISABLED.
The line on the log file contain a PORT RANGE that is different every time , and a Local Port that is always 7070.
I've checked the local port (7070) with :
netstat -ano | findstr "7070" 

and the proces that is listening on that port is Anydesk. ( Is always Anydesk in other PC where i've noticed this behaviour )
I've checked also the PORT RANGE on websites that test open ports , and they says that the port is open.
If i restart the router , the line on log file dissapear and the port result closed.But this situation has repeated several times with the same behaviour but on diferent PC.
How this can be possible , because as i said the option Port Forward on my router is set to disabled.

@John Anydesk works even when there are no port forward on my router logs. But time to time on Router log appear a port forward configured as i've described. But as i said Port forward option on my router is DISABLED. How this port forward is configured?

Sounds like AnyDesk is using UPNP to dynamically config the port forwarding it needs. see if you router has any config settings for UPNP; perhaps you can disable it there.

@FrankThomas UPNP is disabled on router.

@John On my situation the port 7070 result used by Anydesk.

https://support.anydesk.com/knowledge/settings , this article says port 7070 is used for listening by anydesk. What does it mean , connection and listening ?

can you please add the log entries in question or a picture of them to your question?

@FrankThomas Log picture added

Does anybody understand more from the picture i've posted ?

In the General tab in the logs, can you see the events related to the port forwarding? anything in the log about NAT-PMP/PCP or UPNP? can you find the data of the most recent incidence? Also can you confirm you do in fact use Anydesk and have it installed on purpose?

@FrankThomas Unfortunately  the General log is cleared because after  i've found the log on Port forwarding , i've restarted the router to clear the port forward ( that is deleted after i restart the router. After the router is restarted the Port forward does not exist anymore , and this was happened on every episode that i've discovered for other computers). About Anydesk i confirm that in all PC where i discovered port forward i have anydesk and is in use.

You need port forward for someone else to connect into your network, unless you have seriously restrictive firewall rules that deny any explicitly not allowed incoming connections. Most common routers are essentially linux or a Realtime OS running a stateful firewall. If your PC's initiating the connection, the router or firewall is going to let it through, unless the port is explicitly blocked.
A lot of remote desktop software that relies on an external service will initiate the connection from the system you are remoting to, and use a external server to either proxy the connection, or broker the connection between PCs. You're not always going to have an end user with the knowledge, or access to open up a port for you to run remote access on, and this is a simpler solution.
If you're not explicitly using anydesk - its commonly used by scammers. Your problem isn't that anydesk's bypassing your firewall (Its designed to!), its that one of your systems might be compromised.
In theory, on a better firewall or consumer router, you could specifically block that service - but at the risk of sounding alarmist, it sounds like one or more of your systems is compromised, and you might need to act accordingly.

Yes , i'm afraid that a malware can do this ? So on my router Port Forward is Disabled , and i have an open port showed by router logs . So how this can be possible ?

@John I have Norton Deluxe , a scan is made by default every  some hours.

We have a really old and still relevant community faq on this. Security's got a little better since then, but a useful first step would be to actually work out if anydesk is installed, and if someone was convinced to on the network. No point in nuking and paving if the problem is a human being.  A malware might but we don't have enough information to. Norton's also a bit crap these days, I trust MS defender and offline/livecd scans are a good idea in case

there's a rootkit. That said, this smells suspicious in general - and you might want to make sure you've got no suspicious financial transactions, consider changing passwords from a known clean PC and so on.

@JourneymanGeek Ok , but the first step is to know if this situation when Anydesk is involved is a normal activity or no. So can Anydesk open a port forward on routwer even when the port forward router option is set to Disabled ?

@JourneymanGeek, I agree with everything you said, but that doesn't explain the log entries that OP claims indicated that port forwarding configuration had been applied, unless the malware is applied to the router itself. reverse tunnels can't explain the things OP described if the router is actually stating that DNAT rules have been applied.

I'm interpreting it as the connection was started on another port, and is connected over port 7070 - which feels like a fairly normal thing.  To me, at this point, the important thing is working out why and how anydesk is there
